# Incorrect results in implementing euclid's extended algorithm which returns multiple values

Tags: java, oop, object

I am trying to implement Euclid's extended algorithm, and I have to result multiple values here, now the following code doesn't display correct x and y values. I'm following cormen.

```
 package algorithms;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.regex.*;
   import java.text.*;
   import java.math.*;
   import java.awt.geom.*;


public class Euclid {
private int x;
private int y;
private int d;
public static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
        return a;
    else return gcd(b,a%b);
}
public Euclid  gcdExtend(Euclid e, int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
    {
        this.d = a;
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 0;
        return this;
    }

    Euclid e1 = gcdExtend(this,b,a%b);
    Euclid e2 = new Euclid();
   this.d = e1.d;//line1
   this.x= e1.y;//line2
   this.y = e1.x - ((int)Math.floor((a/b)))*e1.y;//line3
   return this;//line 4
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Euclid e = new Euclid();
    e  = e.gcdExtend(e,28,12);
    System.out.println("d = "+ e.d+" x = "+ e.x+" y = "+ e.y);

    }

  }
```

however when i replace line 1 ,2,3,4(as commented in the code) with the following lines, it works absolutely fine. Which OOP concept I'm missing here, I mean why does afetr modification it works fine? Why a new object needs to created and returned?

```
          e2.d = e1.d;//line1
         e2.x= e1.y;//line2
         e2.y = e1.x - ((int)Math.floor((a/b)))*e1.y;//line3
         return e2;//line 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the bug, when I'm returning "this" to a reference type variable "e1", now they point to same object. Hence the next three lines don't execute properly as

```
          this.x = e1.y //essentially means this.x = this.y!
```

and next lines thus don't give proper results as old values of x and y are needed.